# R classification tree use of existing classification system to assign to new sites

Tags: r, tree, cluster-analysis, predict

I used the R package and function, cluster::agnes, to derive a 12 category habitat classification from benthic data ("benthic-data-set"), for the reef system around a tropical atoll (see categories below).

The 12 categories,

```
cluster.number, cluster.name
1, Porites_branching_and_Millipora
2, Rubble
3, Branching_encrusting_Acropora_short_staghorn_coral
4, Physogyra_Acropora_palifera_coral
5, Fleshy_algal_reef
6, Halimeda_and_soft_corals
7, Heterogeneous_seagrass_macro_algae
8, Reef_rock_with_cca_ta
9, High_density_seagrass
10, Sand
11, Hetergoneous_sand_macro_algae
12, Sand_with_Gorgonian_fans_on_reef_rock
```

The 12 categories were comprised from various benthic types,

E.g. Benthic types (only 4 shown)

```
        halimeda rubble     cca.ta       fleshy.algae
ams_n_1 0.000000      0  0.0000000            0.00000
ams_n_2 0.000000      0  0.8130081            0.00000
ams_n_3 0.000000      0 43.3333333           31.66667
ams_n_4 3.333333      0 25.0000000           11.66667
ams_n_5 3.333333      0 25.0000000           11.66667
ams_n_6 0.000000      0 75.5555556           10.00000
```

The 291 sites were classified according to 12 categories, e.g. lets call it "cl12"

```
             cluster.number                     cluster.name
    1                     1  Porites_branching_and_Millipora
    2                     1  Porites_branching_and_Millipora
    3                     2                           Rubble
    4                     2                           Rubble
  290                     9            High_density_seagrass
  291                     7  Heterogeneous_seagrass_macro_algae
```

In a separate survey, I collected video data on fish assemblages and benthic data. The benthic data is in the same format as for the benthic classification (above).I.e. percent coverage for various benthic types.

E.g. of benthic data from fish sites (only 4 shown). I.e. newdata let's call it "minor"

```
       halimeda   rubble     cca.ta      fleshy.algae
1      0.08333333      0  0.1666667                 0
2      0.08333333      0  0.1250000                 0
3      0.00000000      0  0.3333333                 0
4      0.00000000      0  0.1666667                 0
5      0.04166667      0  0.2083333                 0
6      0.00000000      0  0.0000000                 0
```

I would like to apply the 12 category classification already derived, to categorise the habitat of each of the "fish-video-sites" according to the class that it best fits. I.e. fit new data to old classification.

I was wondering how to go about this.

1.) Would a tree::tree analysis be appropriate to a) derive a classification tree from the "benthic-data-set", b) (tree::predict.tree) predict the categories of the "fish-video-sites"?

2.) Can I use the % coverage to generate a classification tree? My limited understanding is that tree analysis uses environmental variables to predict biological variables. So, I am still on track using biological coverage data, to predict assemblages in the first place?

3.) Can one use a combination of environmental and biological data (benthic cover) to derive a classification tree?, e.g. depth and benthic cover types?

e.g.

## Classification tree model (e.g. using only 4 shown categories)

```
tree.m <- tree(factor(cl12$cluster.number) ~ envt$depth + rubble+ cca.ta + fleshy.algae + halimeda, data = benthic.composition)
```

## Predict tree to assign category from new data

```
p.tree <- predict(object = tree.m, newdata = minor)
```

4.) Or is there a more appropriate way of doing this when using biological variables?

Many thanks,
Phil

Comment: You could use a tree for sure.. You could also use a K-nearest neighbors to classify the different types. With 12 measures and a small sample it would be pretty efficient. The advantage of the tree is that it will give you a set of cut points that you can look at, the percent it chose to branch left or write. You are on the right track. You should run a tree and then look at an individual site and see if you think it is right or close to right.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes the tree approach with set cut off points does make it clear why splits are occurring. I am trying to understand if it is OK to use both environmental predictors, e.g. depth, and the composition variables together, e.g. % Acropora coral together in the tree. They are quite different, but is there any reason that they should not be used together when explaining a habitat category?

Comment: I do not feel that there is a reason to exclude valid environmental data whether it is hard science (physical environment), biotic or human. If there is substantial supporting evidence that any given effector might be indicative of the type, try using it. The test will be in your final models ability to predict on previously un-seen data.Whether or not a practice is defensible in your field may be a different story, but you can always talk through it with a senior scientist and get a feel for how to move forward. But see what you can do first!